# UDP real time sending and receiving on Linux on command from control computer

Tags: c++

I am currently working on a project written in C++ involving UDP real time connection. I receive UDP packets from a control computer containing commands to start/stop an infinite while loop that reads data from an IMU and sends that data to the control computer.

My problem is the following: First I implemented an exit condition from the loop using recvfrom() and read(), but the control computer sends a UDP packet every second, which was delaying the whole loop and made sending the data in the desired time interval of 5ms impossible.

I tried to fix this problem by using`fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);`and using only read(), which actually works fine, but I am unsure whether this is a wise idea or not, since I am not checking for errors anymore. Is there any elegant way how to solve this problem? I thought about using Pthreads or something like that, however I have never worked with threads or parallel programming so I would have to spend some time learning that.

I appreciate any advice on that problem you could give me.

Here is a code example:

```
//include
...

int main() {

RNet cmd;               //RNet: struct that contains all the information of the UDP header and the command
RNet* pCmd = &cmd;
ssize_t b;  
int fd2;
struct sockaddr_in snd;  // sender is control computer
socklen_t length;

// further declaration of variables, connecting to socket, etc...
...

fcntl(fd2, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);

while (1)
{
    // read messages from control computer

    if ((b = read(fd2, pCmd, 19)) > 0) {
        memcpy(&cmd, pCmd, b);
    }

    // transmission 

    while (cmd.CLout.MotionCommand == 1)  // MotionCommand: 1 - send messages; 0 - do nothing
    {
        if(time_elapsed >= 5) // elapsed time in ms
        {
            // update sensor values         
            ...
            //sendto ()
            ...
            // update control time, timestamp, etc.
            ...
        }

        if (recvfrom(fd2, pCmd, (int)sizeof(pCmd), 0, (struct sockaddr*) &snd, &length) < 0) {
            perror("error receiving data");
            return 0;
        }

        // checking Control Model Command

        if ((b = read(fd2, pCmd, 19)) > 0) {
            memcpy(&cmd, pCmd, b);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really like the "blocking calls on multiple threads" design. It enables you to have distinct independent tasks, and you don't have to worry about how each task can disturb another. It can have some drawbacks but it is usually a good fit for many needs.

To do that, just use `pthread_create` to create a new thread for each task (you may keep the main thread for one task). In your case, you should have a thread to receive commands, and another one to send your data. You also need for the receiving thread to notify the sending thread of the commands. To do that, you can use some synchronization tool, like a mutex.

Overall, you should have your receiving thread blocking on `recvfrom`, and the sending thread waiting for a signal from the mutex (wait for the mutex to be freed, technically). When the receiving thread receive a start command, it signals the mutex and go back to `recvfrom` (optionally you can set a variable to provide more information to the other thread).

As a comment, remember that UDP are 1-to-many, thus your code here will react to any packet sent to you (even from some random or malicious host). You may want to filter with the remote `sockaddr` after `recvfrom`, or use `connect` + `recv`. It depends on what you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I followed your advice and used pthreads and a mutex and it works perfectly fine! However, could you elaborate on your last comment? I tried both `connect` + `recv` and `recvfrom` with the remote `sockaddr` using my remote pc ip address, but neither worked. There were no errors, but it seemed that `recv` / `recvfrom` were waiting for packets...

Comment: @Fruchtknabe About the remote IP : to use `connect`+`recv` you should specify the remote IP but also the remote port. This can be done on a client, but it's less practical for a server. The filter after `recvfrom` would be just a custom filter to check where the packet comes from. This is a check that you do yourself AFTER recvfrom. `recvfrom` fill the `sockaddr` with the remote host, and you check that it is sensible, because you wouldn't want to process an accidental packet from a random host. This is all optional, for robustness/safety.

Comment: Well, I did specify the remote IP as well as the port, but it didn't work. Unfortunately, I am not very familiar with server/clients. In my opinion the control computer would be the "server" sending the commands and the pc I receive the commands on the "client". Anyway, I was told that I wouldn't have to worry about safety issues, nonetheless I would like to know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: @Fruchtknabe That probably isn't a concern if it works as is. However you may have to handle this point if your code use multiple connections on a single socket.